# Query related to docker commands

Tags: docker, containers

Is there any way to find the time in milliseconds it takes for docker run/pull command to execute?

docker run -d -p 5000:8443 imagerepo\imagename:version

docker pull imagerepo\imagename:version

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`time`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time):

```
$ time docker pull imagerepo\imagename:version
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, for windows, you can use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)'s `Measure-Command`:

```
Measure-Command {start-process docker pull imagerepo\imagename:version -wait}
```

Comment: Thank you it works on linux machines. Do we have equivalent for time windows 2016 server?

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.